# In Classic, how can I track the productivity of my team cleaning up records?

Tags: data, campaign-member, salesforce-classic, enterprise, cleanup

Prereqs:

- Team of 6 employees @ 8/hours a day for 1-2 weeks
- 25,000-35,000 total records affected (Likely won't get to them all)
- Various issues -- missing address, missing phone number, "Unknown Last name", "Unknown Company", Invalid email address.
- No ability to mass update records (different people at different businesses across the country)
- I'm a system admin, but have no apex experience (or workflow, for that matter)

Background:

So it's a slow(ish) time for my team where we switch to cleaning some of the data we get from outside sources. While we're working on a long-term strategy to avoid GIGO, we have records that need cleaning ASAP. However, I want to be able to track this productivity within Salesforce.

Typically, we add them to a Campaign, i.e. "Unknown Company" or "Leads without Email Addresses", but with the sheer size of data we're working with (and the fact one record may be in multiple campaigns), I don't want to create  50,000 - 70,000 Campaign Member records.

My Question (Don't bury the lead, right?):

- Is there a functionality I'm overlooking in Salesforce Classic **or** is there something I'm completely missing around this short-term strategy?

My Ideas:

- Create one Campaign for "2019 Data Cleanup" with custom statuses (such as "Fixed First / Last Name" or "Updated Email".  This won't be able to cover if a record has multiple fixes on it (or if more than one employee has cleaned the record).
- I considered making a custom multi-picklist field on the CampaignMember object, but multi-picklists are insane to track.
- Creating a series of acronyms and then running an activity report (admittedly, this sounds like a terrible idea even as I type it)

Comment: These are `Lead` you are trying to cleanup or other SObjects too?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification -- it would be `Lead` and `Contact` records.

Comment: while I can see why you opted for campaignMember; this seems like a lot of clicking. Why not have some `Cleanse_Action__c` field visible only to your elite team on both Lead and Contact?